# Combine consecutive number range

Tags: perl, numbers, range

I would like to combine consecutive number ranges in Perl. [`Number::Range`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Range) didn't do what I expected:

```perl
use Data::Dumper;
use Number::Range;

say STDERR Dumper(Number::Range->new("1000..5555,5559..9999,5556..5557,5558")->rangeList);
```

results in:

```perl
$VAR1 = [
          5556,
          5558
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          5559,
          9999
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          1000,
          5555
        ];
```

I expected:

```perl
$VAR1 = [
          1000,
          9999
        ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the module represents the data that way internally.  It does not seem to create a merged set of arrays as you had hoped.

If you use the `range` method in scalar context, you will see a single merged range string:

```
use Number::Range;
my $range = Number::Range->new("1000..5555,5559..9999,5556..5557,5558");
my $format = $range->range();
print "$format\n";
```

Prints:

```
1000..9999
```

Comment: The module apparently stores data in a hash

Answer (score 2):

The module's method [range](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number::Range#range) returns the range as a list as you'd expect, in list context

```
say for Number::Range->new("10..12,4,15..18")->range;
```

prints a number per line, sorted. Returns a string in a scalar context, also sorted.

Or, you can construct an object with a list/array (undocumented)

```
my @nums = Number::Range->new(10..12,4,15..18)->range;
say for @nums;
```

Returns them sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Using an alternative module [`Set::IntSpan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan):

```perl
use Set::IntSpan::Fast::XS qw();
say STDERR Set::IntSpan::Fast::XS->new(1000..5555,5559..9999,5556..5557,5558)->as_string;
```